# How to apply rank with multiple measures on tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to apply a rank that could be based in 3 other columns.

I've tried to use the formula

**{FIXED Column1,Column2 : RANK(MIN(Column3),'asc') }**

but I got the error message **level of detail expressions cannot contain table calculations or the attr function in Tableau**

what I wanna do is to have the rank based on the Column1 and Column2 columns and ranking by the dates (Column3)

here is an example of the data (hope it helps)

[image]

Comment: You can do this with a table calc instead of an LOD calc — learn about partitioning and addressing of table calcs in the help

Comment: Hello @AlexBlakemore, thanks for the answer, but I think partitioning function doesn't work on tableau public desktop, at least on my mine doesn't work.

Comment: Partitioning is not a function that you call. It is a concept you need to understand to fully define a table calc. Read the online help sections on table calcs, paying attention to the information on "partitioning and addressing". There are several ways to specify the partitioning you want, from the simply picking the "compute using" menu option to using the "edit Table calc" dialog and selecting specific dimensions. The selected dimensions will be used for addressing. The unselected ones for partitioning. Defining a table calc has 2 parts - the formula itself + the partitioning/addressing

Comment: Ohhh got that, thanks a lot @AlexBlakemore, I'll take a look on the concept.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore -- what if you want to filter on the addressing dimension? Once the filter is applied, the rank() table calc collapses, only comparing the values that survive the filter. I wanted to use an LoD calculation to get around this. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a table calc function from within a LOD calculation.

LOD calcs execute at the data source relatively early in the order of operations. Table calcs execute much later on the client side, operating on the summary query results returned by the data source.

So essentially, table calcs can see the results of LOD calcs and take them as input, but not the other way around.

Tables calcs operate on multiple rows in a summary table at a time, and so can compute values that look across whole sections of that table, such as ranks, running sums, percents etc. Table calcs are the only calculations native to Tableau that take the order of rows in a table into account. Read the help material on table calcs to learn about partitioning and addressing - essential concepts for using table calcs.

All you have to do is create a quick table calc for Rank(column3) is to right click on the measure,  select edit table calculation. --> select  specific dimensions & select both column 1 & 2 --> Restart at every column 2.

Comment: Is there a way allow the user to filter on the "addressing" dimension without affecting the table calculation?

Comment: Can you specify the objective more clearly? If you read about the order of operations in Tableau help, you'll see filters can apply at different steps in the process. You can certainly filter any dimension. You have to decide whether you want the filter to apply before or after the table calc that computes the rank. If the filter happens at the very end, then it is a table calc filter, and essentially hides the data (doesn't display it) rather than exclude it from the originial query